# What are the dates that the yield curve inverted?

Tags: investment-strategies, economics, yield-curve

For the purpose of investing, I've been reading about the yield curve inversion and what it might mean about the economy.

Unfortunately, all articles that I was able to find by searching on Google only seem to be opinion-based, trying to convince the reader that the curve matters or doesn't matter, rather than informing the reader of what the dates actually were.

Could anyone here be kind enough to point me to a resource that actually lists the historical dates that the yield curve inverted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per this article on March 25th, theyield curve inverted on March 22nd :

> The yield on the U.S. 10-year Treasury note on Friday dipped below the yield on the 3-month paper. It was the first time since mid-2007 that the yield curve — which plots bond yields from shortest maturity to highest and is considered a barometer of economic sentiment — inverted."

https://www.cnbc.com/2019/03/25/the-us-bond-yield-curve-has-inverted-heres-what-it-means.html

Should you care to peruse data, you can see graphs of various indexes and securities at Macrotrends.net and you can export the data as well.  For example:

https://www.macrotrends.net/2016/10-year-treasury-bond-rate-yield-chart